# Oracle select from alias VS select from original column

Tags: oracle

When I use alias in where clause, if I select with alias

```
select * from table1 t1 where t1.id in (select key from (select emp_id key from table2 where emp_id in ('123', '456')))
```

This is working as I expected. But if I select with original column name

```
select * from table1 t1 where t1.id in (select emp_id from (select emp_id key from table2 where emp_id in ('123', '456')))
```

This is also working! But seems the where condition: 'emp_id in ('123', '456')' does not take effect.

So what is the difference between alias and the original column name here?

Comment: is there an emp_id in table1?

Comment: IN allows correlation (reference from within to the outer query block) so if there's an emp_id in the outer query block somewhere, it will resolve to it if it can't find any such column in its inner rowsource (and it can't, due to the `key` alias). That's why it's important to explicitly alias your query blocks and prefix your columns so you are clear about what table/block you want the column to come from.

Comment: Thanks so much Paul! Yes there is an emp_id in the outer table. And I think this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think the SQL should have been

```
select * from table1 t1 where t1.id in ('123', '456');
```

There is no meaning to query the same column when you are filtering the same column using where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```sql
select *
from   table1 t1
where  t1.id in (
                  select emp_id
                  from   (
                           select emp_id key
                           from   table2
                           where  emp_id in ('123', '456')
                         )
                )
```

Is being interpreted as:

```sql
select t1.*
from   table1 t1
where  t1.id in (
                  select t1.emp_id
                  from   (
                           select t2.emp_id AS key
                           from   table2 t2
                           where  t2.emp_id in ('123', '456')
                         ) v2
                )
```

and the `emp_id` is being correlated from the outer-query rather than from the inline view of the inner-query.

Yes, it will appear that the condition `where t2.emp_id in ('123', '456')` has no effect because your query could be rewritten as:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  t1.id = t1.emp_id
AND    EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   table2 t2
         WHERE  t2.emp_id IN ('123', '456')
       )
```

Provided the sub-query matches at least one row then the outer query only relies on `table1`.

---

What you would want to do is to use the table/view aliases throughout to ensure the columns are being sourced from the correct location:

```sql
select t1.*
from   table1 t1
where  t1.id in (
                  select v2.emp_id
                  from   (
                           select t2.emp_id AS key
                           from   table2 t2
                           where  t2.emp_id in ('123', '456')
                         ) v2
                )
```

Which should fail with an invalid identifier exception as the inline view `v2` does not have an `emp_id` column and you want to either remove the `AS key` alias in the inner-most sub-query or to use `SELECT v2.key` in the middle sub-query.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QEcurPT4)